# ask the user to select an image from disk and save it in a filesystem in python

Tags: python, opencv

**so this is my code it made the user select an image from his own disk my problem is the moment the user choose an image from his disk I want to store the image in the filesystem(directory) but have no idea how to do it.
so this is the following code when the user is allowed to choose a file(image) from the disk and save it to a particular directory.**

```
import cv2
import os
from tkinter import filedialog



from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import shutil
# importing askopenfile function
# from class filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x100')


def open_file():
   file_path = askopenfile()
   Image = cv2.imread(file_path)
   cv2.imshow("image", Image)
   cv2.waitKey(0)
   #image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(Image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   #cv2.imwrite(file_path, image_gray)
   cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(file_path, '/Users/taifabdullah/desktop/directory'))


btn = Button(root, text='select image', command=lambda: open_file())
btn.pack(side=TOP, pady=10)



mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Python’s shutil module provides a function shutil.copy()

```
shutil.copy(src, dst, *, follow_symlinks=True)
```

It copies the file pointed by src to the directory pointed by dst.

Parameters:

src is the file path in string

dst can be a directory path or another file path in string.

If src is a path of symbolic link,

If follow_symlinks is True, then it will copy the file pointed by symbolic link
.
If follow_symlinks is False, then it create a new similar symbolic link in dst directory.

So what you have to do is add the file path you received from the user as src, and the output file location as dst.